# Examples of Attributed Relational Graphs?

Tags: graph

There are dozens (at least) of datasets of various graph types. Unfortunately (for me) these are generally dominated by examples of graphs involving only node-edge relationships. Alternatively, I am interested in graphs that include node attributes, i.e. attributed relational graphs (ARG). I've been through quite a number of the graph datasets and didn't have any luck finding even a basic example of an ARG.

Any pointers to ARG examples would be greatly appreciated!